# Windows 8 apps - what if I use a non-common font in my app?

Tags: windows-8, fonts

I'm using this [font](http://www.dafont.com/ds-digital.font) in my windows 8 app, and since this font isn't come pre-installed in common computers, would this mean they can't see my app using this font (of course when it's available in the store)? Instead they would just see default Windows font. What could I do about it?

Comment: You have to include font in your project, that's it. Then you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[[Windows 8] Using a custom font in your Windows Store apps](http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2013/04/windows-8-using-a-custom-font-in-your-windows-store-apps/#.UbcUnvm3_ao)